# How to solve undefined method `to_key' error with collection_select - RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying create a collection select, but I got this error:

```
NoMethodError in Deal#selectuser

undefined method `to_key' for #<Conversation::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x1059f4f8>
```

My controller

```
def selectuser
    @conversation = Conversation.involving(current_user)
end
```

My routes

```
  resources :deal, only: [:index, :new, :create, :selectuser] do
     collection do
      get "selectuser" # generate  get "/deal/selectuser"
    end
```

My view (conversation.html.erb)

```
<%= form_for @conversation do |f| %>
  <%= collection_select(:conversation, :recipient_id, Conversation.all, :recipient_id, :title) %>
  <%= f.submit  "Send", class: "btn btn-primary wide" %>
```

Comment: Also your route is wrong. Can you remove `:selectuser` from `resources :deal, only: [:index, :new, :create, :selectuser] do` ?

Comment: @ArupRakshit I removed it...but the wrong persists..

Comment: wrong persist means?

Comment: Yes..I got the same error

Comment: Yes we didn't resolve the error still, I just said to remove unwanted thing. You never need that there. `resources` by convention creates 7 routes. When you don't need all those, then you tell the method `resources` which are the routes you want or skip. But `selectuser` is your custom route, so shouldn't be there.

Comment: I'd like to see the whole controller, or at least the one action (probably edit or create) that is being called. And more of the view. Stack traces are great but occasionally point to the wrong line.

Comment: @MustModify is possible show you the code on pvt chat?

Comment: Depending upon how you've defined the `involving` scope (I assume it's a scope?) Conversation.involving(...) returns an ActiveRecord::Relation that will result in more than one object. There for you likely have to loop through the objects, or at the very least point to a specific one `@conversation.first` or something of that nature. Show us the `involving` scope and perhaps I can give you a complete answer.

Comment: Sure, if that's important to you. I'm mustmodify on freenode. Or you can probably find my domain name and then email address pretty easily, based on my username. :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to write the `collection_select` method as:

```
<%= f.collection_select :recipient_id, Conversation.all, :recipient_id, :title %>
```

Comment: @S_A Can you add the full stack trace please?

Comment: @S_A I need to see the Stack trace to find from which line this error comes, that is needed to debug further. When possible paste the full trace and let me know.

Comment: I got the error on this line:                                     `<% form_for @conversation do |f| %>`